# Почему VS Code нормально не запускает eel?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, eel

Есть самый простой код, запускающий страницу в виде программы с помощью `eel`. Но вот такая незадача, VS Code когда запускает программу не запускает страницу. То есть, мне пишет `Error 404`, но если я запускаю через `cmd`, то  всё ок. Почему и что с этим делать?

Comment: прописать правильно пути? я практически уверен, что vscode у вас не находит саму страницу.

Comment: А куда ещё правильнее? Я просто указываю папку 'web' и файл "index.html". При этом через VS ничего не пашет, а через cmd всё работает. Будь бы что-то в коде не так, то у меня бы ошибки выдавало.

Comment: у вас и выдват ошибки. причем английским по белому написано - 404. VSCode по умолчанию ищет файлы в своей рабочей папке.